# How to debug a Fiddler extension written in .net?

Tags: .net, debugging, fiddler

I wrote a small fiddler (Fiddler Web Debugger (v4.6.2.0)) extension using C#.net. Extension starts to work, but I need to debug the code to identify a bug that fires. What I did is putting the .dll in fiddler script folder and it works. But i dont know how to debug in such cases.

Can someone point me to the steps to debug a fiddler extension?

Thank you

Comment: Project > Properties > Build tab, change the Output path setting so you can avoid the copy.  Debug tab, select Start external program and select Fiddler.  Set the breakpoint and press F5.

Comment: Hi Hans, This is a much better way to do that. I did not realize about changing the output path and do the trick. Thank you very much for stating this. What I did is attaching it to the running fiddler process and it also finally worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not tried this with fiddler, but it might help. This is how I debug some of my APIs.

In Visual Studio you can attach the debugger to a process via the Debug menu.

- Make sure your .PDB files are in the same folder as the DLL in the
  fiddler script folder.
- Put a break-point in your code in Visual Studio.
- Launch fiddler and
  attach to it.

No guarantees that this will work but it's the first thing to try, good luck!

Edit: it may help to run fiddler and/or visual studio with administrator rights. Also, the .PDB files will be in the Debug folder next to the DLL in your solution folder.

Comment: Thank you. Finally it worked. I did not copy the PDB file earlier. Also I executed the following command in fiddler that I found in another post. prefs set fiddler.debug.extensions.verbose True

Answer (score 0):

select Project properties then click `Debug > Start external program` and select `...\ProjectDir\bin\Debug\Fiddler.exe`

and make sure in `Build events > Post-build event command line` you have `copy "$(TargetPath)" "%userprofile%\My Documents\Fiddler2\Scripts\$(TargetFilename)"`